# Бот округляющий числа не делает округления вверх

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, бот

Бот может округлять только в меньшую сторону, а надо в обе
Модуль: pyletelegrambotapi
Изменила так, но все равно работает только в одну сторону(((

```
import time
import telebot
from telebot import types
import datetime
import math

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_menu(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Приветствую, для узнавания даты используйте /date,'
                                           'для округления вниз /down, а вверх /up ')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['date'])
def date(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=str(datetime.datetime.now())[0:19])

@bot.message_handler(commands=['down'])
def down(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Введите число, которое хотите округлить')
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def down(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, math.floor(float(message.text)))


@bot.message_handler(commands=['up'])
def up(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Введите число, которое хотите округлить !')
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def up(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, math.ceil(float(message.text)))


bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

Comment: Поменяйте местами up и down, чтобы сначало было up а потом down :) заработает округление вниз :)

Comment: https://stepik.org/lesson/666085/step/2

Comment: Обработчики выполняются сверху вниз. Если сообщение подходит под условие одного из обработчиков - проверка остановится.